# Log4net not logging if its start by windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

I'm having an issue log4net not logging if it is started by another windows service.

```
// MonitorConsole Path
string pathToConsole = "C:\Monitor\MonitorConsole.exe";

// Start the console
Process.Start(pathToConsole);
```

The console is running properly, but the only issue it not logging.

But, if the console application is started manually by clicking on MonitorConsole.exe, then it is logging into a text file.

Comment: Its a permissions thing most likely

Comment: @TheGeneral I have follow [this](http://www.daoudisamir.com/run-a-process-as-administrator-with-c-programmatically/) method. Also doesn't work.

Comment: As well as permissions issue, if your log4net configuration is in a different file from your app.config, then it is possible your program may not being finding it. When you start your program by clicking on it from explorer, your working directory would be the directory your program is in, but that may not be the case when running as service where the default working folder would be windows\system32. You may way to look at using ProcessStartInfo and set ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a permission problem, the user running the windows service does not have the rights to write in the log folder.
Try running the windows service as You; then it should log. Then you know it logs alright.
 Then look into the rights of the user you want to use for the windows service.

Slightly out of topic: It is usual to have a 'service account' for running a windows service. It is set to not having to change the password at first login and password never expires.